# How create a javascript function that returns a html

Tags: javascript

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

My idea is create a library, function that from index.html returns a html.
For example, I call the function with: `Video.generateIframe("1", controls, "video1")` in index.html

"1" is the id of my video, controls are an array of options to show and "video1" is the id of the div.

My problem is that I dont know how return an html, well... when I execute the javascript returns next error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word.

How can solve it?

```
var Video = (function () {

    'use strict';

    var publicAPIs= {};

    // public method
    publicAPIs.generateIframe = function(id, controls, target) {

        let src = generateSrc(id, controls);

        let iframe = '\n<div id=\'' + target + '\'>\n\t<iframe frameBorder="0" src=\'' + src + '\'>\n\t\t<p>Your browser not support iframes.</p>\n\t</iframe>\n</div>';
    };

    // private method
    var generateSrc = function(id, controls) {
        let urlServer = `http://example.com/panel?selectVideo=${id}`;

        (controls.video) ? urlServer += '&video=1' : urlServer+= '&video=0';
        (controls.stop) ? urlServer += '&stop=1' : urlServer+= '&stop=0';
        (controls.fullscreen) ? urlServer += '&fullscreen=1' : urlServer+= '&fullscreen=0';

        return urlServer;
    };

    return publicAPIs;

})();
```

EDIT:

Sorry, variable is publicAPIs...
I generate a string with div container, now I think that I should append to other html component, a parent html component?

Comment: The symbol `public` is reserved in strict mode. You call it `publicAPIs` later anyway.

Comment: You should return HTML as a string, HTML format is invalid in JavaScript

Comment: `return (<div id={target}>...`  This is known as JSX, popular with React.  You will need a transpiler to be able to return this.  You could return a string like @Madmadi mentions, or return a DOM node, that you prammatically created.

Comment: changed and returned as string, now I have to append to a html parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `public`, `private` keywords are access modifiers of class methods and variables.
>   It's not implemented in JavaScript though. But, the spec reserves them for future usage.

In strict mode, reserved keywords cannot be used. Therefore you've received a `SyntaxError`. Remove the explicit declaration of strict mode or change the variable names to something else corresponding to what you indent.

Comment: Thanks, I changed reserved word.. but the code is written in js

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I hope it is good, or if you can show me a better solution I apreciate it.

```
var Video = (function () {

    'use strict';

    var publicAPIs= {};

    // public method
    publicAPIs.generateIframe = function(id, controls, target) {

        let src = generateSrc(id, controls);

        appendToDiv(src, target);
    };

    // private method
    var appendToDiv = function(link, target) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.frameBorder = 0;
        iframe.width="500px";
        iframe.height="400px";
        iframe.id="iframe-" + target;
        iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
        document.getElementById(target).appendChild(iframe);
    };

    // private method
    var generateSrc = function(id, controls) {
        let urlServer = `http://example.com/panel?selectVideo=${id}`;

        (controls.video) ? urlServer += '&video=1' : urlServer+= '&video=0';
        (controls.stop) ? urlServer += '&stop=1' : urlServer+= '&stop=0';
        (controls.fullscreen) ? urlServer += '&fullscreen=1' : urlServer+= '&fullscreen=0';

        return urlServer;
    };

    return publicAPIs;

})();
```

Comment: Nice, to hear that. But, you shouldn't post answers like this.

Comment: Sorry, How should I post my answers?

Comment: Instead of posting these. You should edit the question itself indicating a edited version of the code.

Comment: ahhh ok.. sorry